# how can I use the CSS selector to solve this

Tags: css

I have a problem with this code

```
<ul style="position: absolute; z-index: 999999999;">
    <li><a href="#" id="home_link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="hits_link">music</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="cinema_link">cinema</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="shows_link">shows</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="timeout_link">timeout</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="win_link">win</a></li>
  </ul>
<div id="logo"></div>
```

I need to change the background position of the div#logo when hover on any "a"

tried this CSS selector with no luck

```
ul li a#hits_link:hover + div#logo{background-position:-198px 0px;}
```

Please Advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There's no selector that produces the behavior you want in CSS. Every CSS selector can only be used to affect an element and its descendants, not its siblings or any other totally unrelated element.

You'll have to use jQuery/JavaScript for this.

Example:

```
$("ul li a").hover(function() {
    // When hovering, change the background-position of the #logo-element
    $("#logo").css("background-position", "-198px 0px");
},function() { 
    // When mouse moves away, revert the background-position
    $("#logo").css("background-position", "0px 0px");
});
```

I made you a fiddle. Treat it with care: http://jsfiddle.net/kMfWk/

Comment: OMG, there is "+" in CSS. Google CSS adjacent selector.

Comment: but I have problem if I used this code which is I already use this function:
`$("a#hits_link").click(function () {$("div#logo").css("background-position","-189px 0");)}` 
so when I hover on another one it will back to background-position", "0px 0px

Comment: Actually, [read this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: Dear god i actually forgot about that one. Thanks.

Comment: Since, you edited, I will remove my downvote as well. But, Please research before you answer randomly.

Comment: @MohammadEreiqat: No, it won't, because the onMouseOver-event will just set the background-position to -198px 0px. It isn't until you mouse out that the background-position is reverted. And why do you have a second function specifically for the link with id "hits_link"? And clicking? I thought you wanted the background-position to move when _hovering_ over _any_ of the links?

Comment: Better would be to `bind` the events `mouseover` and `mouseout` for each element

Comment: How so? `.hover()` binds `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` which are a lot less fiddly to work with than `mouseover` and `mouseout`, which go crazy if you bind them on elements with descendants etc.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot do that, because `#logo` is not an adjacent sibling to `#hits_link`.

I have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JPsYJ/) to demonstrate what do you mean by adjacent sibling.

`#logo` is not related to `#hits_link` in any way, so AFAIK you will need the help of a js snippet to do something like that.

Using JQuery.. you can do something similar to this

```
$("#hits_link").hover(function() {
    $("#logo").css("background-position", "-198px 0px");
},function() { 
    $("#logo").css("background-position", "0px 0px");
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JPsYJ/1/) to that as well.

**Update:**
On that case, the second function is reverting the background position to 0 0.

use only this, if you want it to stay like that

```
$("#hits_link").hover(function() {
    $("#logo").css("background-position", "-198px 0px");
});
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JPsYJ/2/)

Comment: but I have problem if I used this code which is I already use this function:
`$("a#hits_link").click(function () {$("div#logo").css("background-position","-189px 0");)}` 
so when I hover on another one it will back to background-position", "0px 0px